# How to save it in entity right

Tags: c#, entity-framework, crud

Assume i have a big entity and want to create a typical CRUD application. A user shouldn't have the ability to save some fields of my entity.

So i see two ways to implement change-save logic:

a)

1. Get entity from DB
2. Out to page with all fields(fields which user shoudnt change outed as hidden inputs)
3. Take entity by post method
4. Attach to context and save

In this case i need to out on page useless fields. And it is sucks no doubt.

b)

1. Get entity from DB
2. Out to page only necessary fields(fields which user can change)
3. Take entity by post method
4. Get entity from DB
5. Fill DB entity by new values and save

In this case i need to do additional query to DB. So it is not good for perfomance.

What is right way?

Answer (score 2):

or C):

1. Get entity from DB
2. Map entity to ViewModel with only the allowed fields
3. Post ViewModel with data back to controller
4. Map ViewModel back to Entity
5. Attach and Save.

EDIT:
I highly recommend [AutoMapper](http://nuget.org/packages/automapper) for the mapping to and fro

Comment: "Map ViewModel back to Entity" How can i do it? Where i can get entity?

Comment: Your entity is what will end up back in your database, in other words it's the class in your Code first model, or your entity framework model

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly enough, I just watched a video made by Julie Lerman in which she discusses almost the exact same problem. Neither of your solutions was what she went with:

Have a separate entity class that contains the fields that you want to go on the screen, but still maps to the same table that the regular one does. Then just query that DbSet for grabbing the entity (with only those fields), and save the updates to that.

She mentioned this while discussing implementing Domain Driven Design on top of Entity Framework. So that if you have different DbContexts for different functions in your application, you can still have a DbContext that you're using write to the table, but you can restrict which fields that context can write to.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use different `ViewModels` for different tasks. If you want to show the user some fields of the `Model` to edit, then you can do so using `EditModel` and while saving use `CreateModel` to create and populate the database. This way you can avoid your database structure to be known to the user, thus ensuring protection and security.